# Top border is missing in some of the columns in excel report using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am generating an excel report using vb.net. Some of the borders are missing in the report. Top border of E32 F32,G32 H32 is missing and right of H32 is missing.Below is my code. Even top right of B32 is missing.[image]

```
      With oSheet.Range("E" & count)
            .Merge()
            .HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin
            .Value = "For the month"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .ColumnWidth = 20

        End With
        oSheet.Range("E36:F36").Merge()
        With oSheet.Range("E" & count + 1)
            .HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin
            .Font.Bold = True
            .ColumnWidth = 20

        End With

        With oSheet.Range("G" & count)
            .Merge()
            .HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin
            .Value = "Since Inspection"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .ColumnWidth = 20

        End With
        oSheet.Range("G36:H36").Merge()
        count += 1
        With oSheet.Range("E" & count)
            .Merge()
            .HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin
            .Value = "No. of Loans"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .ColumnWidth = 20
            .WrapText = True
        End With
        With oSheet.Range("F" & count)
            .Merge()
            .HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin
            .Value = "Amount"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .ColumnWidth = 20
            .WrapText = True
        End With
        With oSheet.Range("G" & count)
            .Merge()
            .HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin
            .Value = "No. of Loans"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .ColumnWidth = 20
            .WrapText = True
        End With
        With oSheet.Range("H" & count)
            .Merge()
            .HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
            .Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin
            .Value = "Amount"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .ColumnWidth = 20
            .WrapText = True
        End With
        count += 1
        oExcel.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to do that?

If so, i normally use code like the following to create a bordered cell;

```
Dim sPathFileExcel As String = "C:\test.xlsx"
Dim oAppExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim WB As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
WB = oAppExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPathFileExcel)
Dim WS As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = WB.Sheets(1)

Dim styBorder As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Style = WS.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("styBorder")

            With styBorder

                .Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
                .Borders.Item(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
                .Borders.Item(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
                .Borders.Item(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
                .Borders.Item(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone

            End With

Dim rngActual As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = WS.Cells(2, 3)

rngActual.Style = "styBorder"
```